# Joomla! Installation hanging

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, php-5.6

I am having an odd issue (I think, as I have done about 3 hours digging throu SO and Google).

During The install of Joomla 3 it simply freezes.  I am going to include a screenshot.  my `php.ini` `timeout` is set to `300` and my `max_execution` is set to `300` as well.  `File uploads` set to `1024 MB`.

In addition to that I have `chmod` the `/joomla` directory to `777` (as a test) and still failing.

I have changed the to lines in `libraries/joomla/filter/input.php`

FROM:

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source); // decimal notation
$source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', "utf8_encode(chr(0x\\1))", $source); // hex notation
```

TO:

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x(\d+);/mi', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr('0x'.$m[1]));}, $source); // decimal notation
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr('0x'.$m[1]));}, $source); // hex notation
```

I have also made these changes outlined here --> http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-troubleshooter-how-to-deal-with-deprecated-function-iconv_set_encoding-error.html#gref  due to a deprecated function issue.

In addition to that I have made sure that that `/php5/sessions/` permissions settings are sufficient. I am truly stuck and not sure what other steps I can take.

It is also worth mentioning that there are zero errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

This is a clean log after an Apache restart and installation run:

```
[Sat Dec 12 19:19:13.360609 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29099] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 12 19:19:13.360645 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29099] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

This is the Overview of the install:

[image: Confirmation of configuration]

And this is where is freezes when I hit "Next":

[image: Freezes]
Ideas?

`PHP 5.6.11`
`APACHE 2.4.12`
`MySQL 5.6.27`

Comment: Can you share your apache error log

Comment: ^^ Edited OP ...  Log is 100% clean as far as PHP errors are concerned.